# c# htmlagility pack conditional select node

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am not sure the title suits my problem.
I have html like below

```
<table id="searchResultsTable" class="">

<tbody>
    <tr class="searchResultsItem even     ">
            <td class="searchResultsPriceValue">
            <div> 26.500 TL</div></td>
        <td class="searchResultsTitleValue ">
                    <a class="classifiedTitle" href="xxxx"> some text</a>
    </tr>
    <tr class="searchResultsItem odd     ">
    .
    //same as "searchResultsItem even     "
    .
    </tr>   

</tbody>

</table>
```

I am new to htmlagility pack. I have succeed in getting the price value of both "searchResultsItem even"  and "searchResultsItem odd".

I want to get href value if the price is below or above some value. I can get href but all time for "searchResultsItem even". I want to get href if even's price value matches my condition for even and if odd matches my condition i want to get for odd.

below is my code

```
foreach (HtmlNode node1 in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='searchResultsTable']"))
                {
                    foreach (HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes("//td[@class='searchResultsPriceValue']"))
                    {
                        string price = node2.InnerText.ToString();
                        price = price.Trim().Replace(".", String.Empty);
                        price = price.Replace("TL", String.Empty);
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(price) < 28000)
                        {
                            HtmlNode node3 = node.SelectSingle(".//a[@class='classifiedTitle']");
                            listBox1.Items.Add(node3.Attributes["href"].Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get the `tr` class name as an attribute value. Loop through rows first, then `td`s.

```
foreach (HtmlNode node1 in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='searchResultsTable']"))
{
  foreach (HtmlNode tr in table.SelectNodes("//tr"))
  {
    var @class = tr.GetAttributeValue("class", string.Empty);
    switch (@class) {
          // rest of your parsing
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how GetAttributeValue works. I run your code but @class variable is always empty